# GPS inaccuracy result in wrong travel duration returned by Google distance matrix API

Tags: api, gps, location

I m using google distance matrix api to calculate estimated arrival time everytime the location is updated. However the result duration sometimes become longer as the api consider me at the other side of road and have to make a u turn... So the duration become longer
May i know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do more GPS measurements and calculate the mean is one way to do this.

Comment: Any example of source code?